# conventions in creating relationships

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm new to EF, just have some questions on naming conventions in EF, let's say we have two classes `Student` and `Teacher` as

```
public class Student
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Q1- if Teacher(one) has one to many relationship to Student(many), we know that we need need to add foreign key property and navigation property to Student and modify Teacher class as:

```
public class Teacher
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

so my first question,without attribute or Fluent API, Can I name the navigation property any name other than "Students"? Does the convention works in this way: the type in the IEnumerable is `Student`, so the property name has to be the type's name plus 's' in the end as `Students`?

Q2-if Student and Teacher have many-to-many relationship, we need to create a junction class(Let's say it is called `Enrolment` , and then modify `Student` and `Teacher` as:

```
public class Student
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Enrolment> details { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Enrolment> details { get; set; }
}
```

what's the naming convention for both navigation properties in this case? does it mean that we can name the navigation property whatever we want as long as both navigation properties has the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly, the name of the *collection* navigation property doesn't matter - it could be whatever you like. And since many-to-many via explicit link entity are represented with 2 separate one-to-many relationships, the name of the collection property in both principal entities doesn't matter and also does not need to be one and the same.

The only name which affects the conventional FK property/column name is the name of the principal entity class, the name of the principal entity key property and the name of the *reference* navigation property in dependent entity if present.

It's partially explained in the [Relationships - Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#conventions) section of the EF Core documentation:

> If the dependent entity contains a property named <`primary key property name>`, <`navigation property name><primary key property name`>, or <`principal entity name><primary key property name`> then it will be configured as the foreign key.

Note that for one-to-many relationship, the *one* side entity is always the **principal** and *many* side entity is always the **dependent**.